# Simulating Touch on a Windows Surface without the use of aria-haspop

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8, touch

[Microsoft suggests using aria-haspop="true" to simulate hover on touch-enabled devices.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[This is also the correct use in the W3 roles model spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-haspopup)

Without including aria-haspop="true" I am unable to keep a submenu open when I click, and when I hold down a click it will fire a "right-click".

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/MathiasaurusRex/pen/gpagqE)

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li aria-haspopup="false">
    <a href="#">aria-haspopup="false"</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub Menu Item 1</li>
      <li>Sub Menu Item 2</li>
      <li>Sub Menu Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li aria-haspopup="true">
    <a href="#">aria-haspop="true"</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub Menu Item 1</li>
      <li>Sub Menu Item 2</li>
      <li>Sub Menu Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #1abc9c;
}
.menu > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.menu > li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background:  #1abc9c;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}
.menu .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.menu .sub-menu li {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

Let's try to make the web a less accessible place. Is there any way to have the sub-menu work just as well without adding aria tags on a windows surface device? Preferably using only CSS. Javascript would be acceptable but less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

In the same Microsoft guide you linked, they recommend using the `onclick` event to show content.

> The best practice is to not use hover to hide content that a user can interact with. Instead, consider using the **onclick** event to toggle the visibility.

The challenge, of course, is that your menu items are also links, and clicking on a link is likely to take you to another page. Only if they really are dead anchors that go nowhere (as in your example code) is it safe to use their `onclick` events to show or hide the submenus.

Here's some example code that uses `onclick` to show the submenus instead of using CSS `:hover`. Note that my example directly assigns the handlers for the sake of brevity, but better practice would be to use the `addEventListener()` method.

```js
var parentMenuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu > li");
var len = parentMenuItems.length;
while (len--) {
  parentMenuItems[len].onclick = showSubMenu;
  parentMenuItems[len].onmouseenter = showSubMenu;
  parentMenuItems[len].onmouseleave = hideSubMenu;
}
function showSubMenu() {
  this.querySelector(".sub-menu").style.display = "block";
}
function hideSubMenu() {
  this.querySelector(".sub-menu").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #1abc9c;
}
.menu > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
.menu > li .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: #1abc9c;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}
.menu .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu .sub-menu li {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li aria-haspopup="false">
    <a href="#">aria-haspopup="false"</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub Menu Item 1</li>
      <li>Sub Menu Item 2</li>
      <li>Sub Menu Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li aria-haspopup="true">
    <a href="#">aria-haspop="true"</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub Menu Item 1</li>
      <li>Sub Menu Item 2</li>
      <li>Sub Menu Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's good which is why I up-voted. Going to keep the question unanswered to see if someone else comes across it in the future with other interesting ideas.